# Scientific format on Word table formula

Tags: ms-word, format

I recently learned about formulas on Word tables and it's being pretty useful although not as versatile as Excel it might work with my large data set. My only issue so far is formatting.

I would like to format in scientific notation. I tried the formats from Excel without any luck:

- ##0.0E+00

Any idea?

Comment: The facility to do this is definitely not built into Word. But do you know what range of values your numbers could take? I ask because it is possible, up to a point, to write some Word field code to generate a scientific format number from an "ordinary" one, but my suspicion is that for (positive) numbers higher than (say) 1.0E+14 and smaller than 1.0E-14, it may be difficult to deal reliably with some rounding problems that Word field arithmetic can introduce.

Comment: I believe it goes up to 1.0E-16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word's field code language does not have a format specifier for this, so you have to take another approach, e.g.

1. Embed an Excel table in your Word document instead of using a Word
   table
2. Use VBA instead of Field codes to calculate the table values
3. Use a field code calculation to format the number
4. Use a DATABASE field in conjunction with an Access database to
   format the number

(1) is probably your best bet, especially if the calculations are complex, because Word table formulas are really limited compared to Excel's

(2) means that you lose the benefit of what Word's field codes do.

(3) is clunky, but I think it can be done. However, the biggest problem is that unlike Excel, Word does not make a distinction between the value of the cell and the formatted value of the cell. For example, suppose a cell calculates an intermediate result of 1234.5678 that you want to display, and you are displaying results to 2DP. Then you have to put a calculation in the cell that will result in 1.23E+3. But when you now reference that cell in another calculation, its value will be 1230, not 1234.5678. So if you need to do that, I think you will have to use one cell for the real intermediate result, and another for the display. Also, the methods described here aren't going to deal properly with variable precision.

(4) is *very* clunky. It is for Windows versions of Word only. It's actually only really suited to formatting values outside a table, because the DATABASE field cannot be used inside a Word table. It means you have to create an external Access/Jet .mdb and put it somewhere where Word can open it. If you want to distribute your solution, that can be difficult. You then use the Jet SQL format() function to format each number. Word will execute a query every time you want to format a number.

The approach for (3) was originally created by macropod - you can find his tutorial on "Word Field Maths" [here](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/154369-Microsoft-Word-Field-Maths-Tutorial) (you may need to sign up to get it).

I don't actually have the current version of the tutorial but the version I have seen only deals with positive numbers (and 0) from about 1.E-9 up to about 1.0E+10. It has fields like this:

```
{QUOTE
{SET a {SourceVal}}
{SET
b{=9-(a<10^9)-(a<10^8)-(a<10^7)-(a<10^6)-(a<10^5)-(a<10^4)-(a<10^3)-(a<10^2)
-(a<10^1)-(a<10^0)-(a<10^-1)-(a<10^-2)-(a<10^-3)-(a<10^-4)-(a<10^-5)-(a<10^-
6)-(a<10^-7)-(a<10^-8)}}
{SET c{=int(a/10^b)+mod(a,10^b)/10^b}}
{c \# 0.00}E{b \# +00;-00}}
```

All the {} are the special field code brace pairs that you can insert in Windows Word using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd>. In the case of table fields, what you would do is copy the entire set of fields into the table cell, and replace the {SourceVal} field by the {=} field that you actually want in the cell.

However, I think there are some problems in the version of the formula I have quoted, e.g.

1. It is obviously trying to create a normalised result, but if
   SourceVal is a power of 10 >= 100000, the formula will count the
   powers of 10 wrongly - e.g. 100000 is converted to 10.00E+04 when it
   should be 1.00E+05
2. If the number would result in a normalised value of 9.99xEy, where
   "x" is 5,6,7,8,9, the number will be rounded up to 10 and again will
   not be properly normalised.
3. I think the formula is intended to put a "+" sign in from the power
   of 10 when it is a positive, no sign if it is 0, and a "-" if it is negative, i.e. 0.1 would be 1.00E-01, 10 would be 1.00E+01 and 1 would be 1.00E 00. There is nothing wrong with that, but if you also want Word to *recognise* the formatted values as numbers, you have to format 1 as 1.00E+00 (1.00E-00 does not work either)
4. 0 is formatted as 0.00E-09, which is also valid, but not normalised. Since the definition of normalisation doesn't work for 0 there isn't really a correct choice, but maybe it should be 0.00E+00

I believe problem (1) results from the fact that when Word calculates 10^6 (for example), the result is not exactly 1000000. (You can check using { =10^6-1000000 #0. }

Finally, macropod clearly had a reason to calculate the value of c using the int and mod functions. I don't know why, but it may become apparent to you, in which case you will probably need to modify the version I give below.

Although it is a lot less clear, I think the following coding will probably solve all those problems, but you should check.

First, at the beginning of your document (or perhaps in a header) you need to put the following fields and execute them:

```
{ SET p_1 100000000000000000 }{ SET p_2 10000000000000000 }{ SET p_3 1000000000000000 }
{ SET p_4 100000000000000 }{ SET p_5 10000000000000 }{ SET p_6 1000000000000 }
{ SET p_7 100000000000 }{ SET p_8 10000000000 }{ SET p_9 1000000000 }{ SET p_10 100000000 }
{ SET p_11 10000000 }{ SET p_12 1000000 }{ SET p_13 100000 }{ SET p_14 10000 }
{ SET p_15 1000 }{ SET p_16 100 }{ SET p_17 10 }{ SET p_18 1 }{ SET p_19 .1 }
{ SET p_20 .01 }{ SET p_21 .001 }{ SET p_22 .0001 }{ SET p_23 .00001 }{ SET p_24 .000001 }
{ SET p_25 .0000001 }{ SET p_26 .00000001 }{ SET p_27 .000000001 }{ SET p_28 .0000000001 }
{ SET p_29 .00000000001 }{ SET p_30 .000000000001 }{ SET p_31 .0000000000001 }
{ SET p_32 .00000000000001 }{ SET p_33 .000000000000001 }{ SET p_34 .0000000000000001 }
```

By using these, we avoid calculating powers of 10.

Then use the following fields to perform the format:

```
{ QUOTE
{ SET w { SourceVal } }
{ SET x { =abs(w) }
{ SET y { =1+(x<p_1)+(x<p_2)+(x<p_3)+(x<p_4)+(x<p_5)+(x<p_6)+(x<p_7)+(x<p_8)+(x<p_9)+(x<p_10)+(x<p_11)+(x<p_12)+(x<p_13)+(x<p_14)+(x<p_15)+(x<p_16)+(x<p_17)+(x<p_18)+(x<p_19)+(x<p_20)+(x<p_21)+(x<p_22)+(x<p_23)+(x<p_24)+(x<p_25)+(x<p_26)+(x<p_27)+(x<p_28)+(x<p_29)+(x<p_30)+(x<p_31) +(x<p_32) +(x<p_33) +(x<p_34) }
{ IF w = 35 "0.00E+00" 
"{ =w \#;- }{ SET z "p_{ y }" }{ IF { =x/{ z } \#0.00 } = 10 
"{ SET y { =y-1 } }{ SET z "p_{ y }" }"
}{ =x/{ z } \#0.00 }{ =18-w \#'+'00;00 }" } }
```

(I may have missed a closing brace or a " mark out in that lot)

You can put all that lot on one line. You can also leave a lot of spaces out of that if you prefer:

```
{QUOTE
{SET w {SourceVal}}
{SET x {=abs(w)}
{SET y {=1+(x<p_1)+(x<p_2)+(x<p_3)+(x<p_4)+(x<p_5)+(x<p_6)+(x<p_7)+(x<p_8)+(x<p_9)+(x<p_10)+(x<p_11)+(x<p_12)+(x<p_13)+(x<p_14)+(x<p_15)+(x<p_16)+(x<p_17)+(x<p_18)+(x<p_19)+(x<p_20)+(x<p_21)+(x<p_22)+(x<p_23)+(x<p_24)+(x<p_25)+(x<p_26)+(x<p_27)+(x<p_28)+(x<p_29)+(x<p_30)+(x<p_31)+(x<p_32)+(x<p_33)+(x<p_34)}
{IF w = 35 "0.00E+00" 
"{=w \#;-}{SET z "p_{y}"}{IF {=x/{z} \#0.00} = 10 
"{SET y {=y-1}}{SET z "p_{y}"}"}{=x/{z} \#0.00}{=18-w \#'+'00;00}"}}
```

You can obviously modify the precision with a few small changes.

Finally, if you  want to try the DATABASE field approach, what you will need is to put the DATABASE fields outside the table, then copy their results back into the appropriate cells in the table. e.g. suppose you want E5 to contain the formatted result of E2*E3*E4. Then one way to proceed is to bookmark the table (let's call the bookmark "mytable"). Outside the table, you can then reference the cells, but only by enclosing their references in a suitable function.

In this case, you can do

```
{ =PRODUCT(mytable E2:E4) }
```

or

```
{ =PRODUCT(mytable E2,mytable E3, mytable E4) }
```

but if instead you needed E2+(E3/E4), you would probably need something like

```
{ =SUM(mytable E2,{=SUM(mytable E3)}/{=SUM(mytable E4)})}
```

Or you might be able to do the calculation in a cell, e.g. F4, then use the following field code to use the result outside the table:

```
{ =SUM(mytable F4) }
```

For the formatting, let's say you have a database called a.mdb in c:\a. Then you can use (say)

```
{ SET result { QUOTE { DATABASE \d "c:\\a\\a.mdb" \s "SELECT format({ =SUM(mytable F4) },'Scientific')" } } }
```

Then in E5 you could put

```
{ =result }
```

You can modify the formatting options - see, e.g. [the MS documentation for the format function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634206.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. I ended up using Excel instead and then copying the tables into the word document. Less painful than everything that you mention above. Still the answer is really helpful specially for other people ending up here.